# Why 'timestamp not null' is resulting in default being set to 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'?

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

When I create a new table

```
create table test(rId int auto_increment, createtimestamp timestamp not null, PRIMARY KEY (rId));
```

it creates a table with default schema for 
`createtimestamp` as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Expected behavior was no default set.  But it's getting set to default: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Why is this happening?

I can alter this after the creation with `ALTER TABLE test CHANGE COLUMN createtimestamp createtimestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;` but can't alter it to `ALTER TABLE test CHANGE COLUMN createtimestamp createtimestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ;`.

It looks like a default has to be specified but this is exactly what I don't want. How can I achieve a behavior where the default is not set and schema is not null, just after creation of table and without any alteration required?

MySql Version: 5.5.49

Comment: [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html): "With neither DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP nor ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, it is the same as specifying both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP... To suppress automatic properties for the first TIMESTAMP column, do either of the following..."

Answer (score 0):

The initial answer is correct, but if it's not acceptable to have a default or a NULL in the definition, one might consider either using datetime instead, or upgrading to MySQL 5.6 which allows behaviour change http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp.